# Interpolated SQL to LINQ-query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How would the following SQL-query translate to LINQ:

```
SELECT TOP 2 A.* FROM UserInterests AS UIa
INNER JOIN UserInterests AS UIb ON UIb.InterestId = UIa.InterestId
INNER JOIN AspNetUsers AS A ON A.Id = UIb.ApplicationUserId
WHERE UIa.ApplicationUserId = {userId}
AND NOT UIb.ApplicationUserId = {userId}
AND (
    A.Location LIKE {locationSubString + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[0] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[1] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[2] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[3] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[4] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[5] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[6] + "%"} OR
    A.Location LIKE {neighbours[7] + "%"}
)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I am selecting two random users who are near me and who have the same interests. The query above is executed with DbSet.FromSqlInterpolated. The userId-variable is my id and the locationSubString + neighbours-array are geohashes.

I have the following, but I am not sure how I would match the interests:

```
dbContext.Users.Where(u => (
    u.Location.StartsWith(locationSubString) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[0]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[1]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[2]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[3]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[4]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[5]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[6]) ||
    u.Location.StartsWith(neighbours[7])
) && u.Id != userId
).Include(u => u.Interests)
```

Can this be done in one query? Or do I need to query my own interests first and then compare it with that list like so (myInterests is a list):

```
...
.Include(u => u.Interests)
.Where(u => u.Interests.Any(i => myInterests.Contains(i)))
```

Comment: Please post what you tried and where you got stuck. The start seems simple enough, then you will need EF.Functions.Like.

Comment: @JakubFojtik ofcourse! I've added what I got right now, but I have used string.StartsWith. Is this there a reason you mentioned EF.Functions.Like instead of StartsWith or is it just a small difference?

Comment: You are right, string.StartsWith does the job. EF's Like just allows crazier patterns like 'The % thing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the matching code I came up with:

```
var currentPersonId = 1;
var data = context.UserInterests
  .Join(context.UserInterests, x => x.InterestID, x => x.InterestID, (a, b) => new { CurrentInterest = a, MatchedInterest = b })
  .Where(x => x.CurrentInterest.UserID == currentPersonId && x.MatchedInterest.UserID != currentPersonId)
  .Select(x => x.MatchedInterest.User)
  .Distinct()
  .Where(x => x.Location.StartsWith("a"))
  .OrderBy(u => Guid.NewGuid())
  .Take(2)
  .ToArray();
```

You can see it work on sample data [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pKujo8).